# How does sbrk know what address to start allocation?

Tags: memory-management, assembly, mips, sbrk

I'm a beginner at assembly, and I'm having a hard time getting sbrk to allocate memory the way I want it to. I ultimately want to create a 2D array, first by allocating one column and then going through each of the row, allocating one row at a time. However, I noticed that when I use sbrk for the second time, it does't start from an unused memory location but overwrites the memory address that I already allocated. So to find out what I'm doing wrong, I decided to use a 1D array for now.

When I first use the

```
li $a0, 3   # array of length 3
li $v0, 9
syscall
```

it allocates memory block `0x10040000`. Then I input 3 integers to those three locations that I allocated. After that, I do another sbrk just to see what address it starts from. When I do that it allocates `0x10040004`, overwriting one of the integers that I input. Following is the code that I used.

```
# test with 1D array
# $s0 => length of array
# $s1 => address of first element in array
# $s2 => address of second sbrk

li $s0, 3

move $a0, $s0
li $v0, 9
syscall
move $s1, $v0

# use $t1 to go through array
move $t1, $s1

# read first int
li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, ($t1)

addi $t1, $t1, 4

# read second int
li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, ($t1)

addi $t1, $t1, 4

# read third int
li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, ($t1)

# use sbrk for second time
li $a0, 5
li $v0, 9
syscall
move $s2, $v0

# exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

When this program finishes, `$s1 = 0x10040000` and `$s2 = 0x10040004`.

Why does sbrk allocate memory starting from where it's already allocated? Is there any way to tell it to start from a specific address? Please correct me if I'm doing something that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units you should pass `sbrk` are bytes.  3 integers is `3 * sizeof(int)` or (on most architectures) 12.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. I can't believe it took me over 4 hours and I still couldn't figure that out... :(